# Unable to dismiss the dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, coded-ui-tests

I am automating a desktop application using Coded-UI where I need to dismiss one dialog popup just by clicking Yes on that.Can any one help me which property I need to use?
I tried below code but no use

```
UITestControl c = new UITestControl();
c.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
c.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Dialog");
c.SearchProperties.Add("ClassName", "#32770");
c.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Desktop application");

DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();
Form f = new Form();

dr = f.ShowDialog();
if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    MessageBox.Show("user clicked on yes");
}
else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
{
    MessageBox.Show("user clicked on no");
}
```

Comment: Elaborate your question. Show some code related to the issue. Show what you have tried till now and we can take it further.

Comment: @MattMurdock updated my question with some sample code

Comment: You appear to be mixing Coded UI actions in the same code as your application code. That will not work. Keep the application and Coded UI separate, they could be in two different Visual Studio solutions.